# Remove display names from big list of emails

Tags: regex, powershell

I have copied and pasted the To field of outlook with a lot of addresses.

```
first last alast@email.com; bob dole bdole@emaill.com; sam smith ssmith@email.com
```

This has a few dozen addresses in this format.

Can anyone here dream up a regular expression that will help me clean up this list to be just one email per line?

I tried opening in excel after replacing `;` with a `,` to open as a `.csv`, but the addresses are not in one column

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`MailAddress` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-8.0) instead of regex:

```bash
$mails = 'first last alast@email.com; bob dole bdole@emaill.com; sam smith ssmith@email.com'
$mails.Split(';') | ForEach-Object { [mailaddress]::new($_).Address }
```